# Custom DefaultTokenServices bean not being used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot Rest API using JWT and OAuth2

Spring Boot 1.5.10 using the default versions for spring security starter and the oauth2 and jwt modules.

In my Authorization Server config I am declaring a custom `DefaultTokenServices` based off of this guide here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${tokenSigningKey:sdf8234kjdhgD}")
    private String tokenSigningKey;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(tokenSigningKey);
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new CustomJwtJdbcTokenStore(accessTokenConverter(), dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomAccessTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

}
```

However the actual `DefaultTokenServices` being used is the one being built behind the scenes in `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`

Here is the relevant code from that class

```
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices getDefaultAuthorizationServerTokenServices() {
        if (defaultTokenServices != null) {
            return defaultTokenServices;
        }
        this.defaultTokenServices = createDefaultTokenServices();
        return this.defaultTokenServices;
    }

    private DefaultTokenServices createDefaultTokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(reuseRefreshToken);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService());
        tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
        addUserDetailsService(tokenServices, this.userDetailsService);
        return tokenServices;
    }
```

I came acrossed an answer online that suggested setting the `DefaultTokenServices` in `public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)` method, but when I do that it DOES use my custom bean, but for some reason the tokens it produces are not in JWT format, it appears to be using the default simple format of the tokens. I just don't know why it's not using my custom bean because in the guide I am following it is not declared in this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same happened to me yesterday. Effectively, you need to add the `DefaultTokenServices` to the endpoints. The reason why it does not come in JWT format is because that format is not added by default. You need to add the JWT format bean to your `DefaultTokenServices`.

Also, you need to do more or less the same than what `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` is doing to generate the `DefaultTokenServices` in `createDefaultTokenServices()`, just replacing the details you need. Here it is the relevant code you need to add to your Authorization Server config:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain, ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    defaultTokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    addUserDetailsService(defaultTokenServices,userDetailsService);
    return defaultTokenServices;
}

private void addUserDetailsService(DefaultTokenServices tokenServices, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    if (userDetailsService != null) {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(
                userDetailsService));
        tokenServices
                .setAuthenticationManager(new ProviderManager(Arrays.<AuthenticationProvider> asList(provider)));
    }
}
```

And add the `tokenServices` method to the configure method of your Authorization Server config:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices(tokenEnhancerChain,endpoints.getClientDetailsService()));
}
```

This worked for me. Let me know if you ran into any issue.